# Backbonejs Optional parameter in routes is not matching url

Tags: backbone.js

In mY routes this is detectable

'resume/:assessmentId/:resultId/:skip': 'resume'

Now when i navigate to 
resume/a/b/c
 every thing works and resume function will call

but when i do this 
'resume/:assessmentId/:resultId(/:skip)': 'resume'

and navigate to same url it will not work

Actually my url is resume/a(required)/b(required)/c(optional)

Comment: which Backbone version are you using?

Comment: it's Backbone.js 0.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optional parts via parenthesis are supported since version 0.9.9

[Backbone changelog](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog)